# Trigger sound play() with NSSpeechRecognizer Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to trigger a sound after I say a word. The speech recognizer recognizes the word when I say it and I've set it up so it puts out a string each time I say the command. What I'd like to do is trigger a sound after I say that specific word. This is what I have so far.

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSSpeechRecognizerDelegate {

var ping = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ping", ofType: "mp3")!)
var pingAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var sr = NSSpeechRecognizer()
@IBOutlet var output: NSTextView?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    pingAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ping, error: nil)

    sr.delegate = self
    sr.commands = ["Ping", "Ping Mac"]
    sr.startListening()

}

func speechRecognizer(sender: NSSpeechRecognizer, didRecognizeCommand command: AnyObject?) {
    output!.string! += "\(command)\n"
    pingAudioPlayer.play()
}
override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSSpeechRecognizerDelegate {

var ping = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ping", ofType: "mp3")!)
let pingAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var sr = NSSpeechRecognizer()
@IBOutlet var output: NSTextView?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    sr.delegate = self
    sr.commands = ["Ping", "Ping Mac"]
    sr.startListening()


}

func speechRecognizer(sender: NSSpeechRecognizer, didRecognizeCommand command: AnyObject?) {
    output!.string! += "\(command)\n"
    var pingAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ping, error: nil)
    pingAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    pingAudioPlayer.play()
}
override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
```

}

Not sure why the audio player is not playing the sound once the word is recognized. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't telling the audio player which sound to play. Try this:

```
func speechRecognizer(sender: NSSpeechRecognizer, didRecognizeCommand command: AnyObject?) {

do{
    let pingAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:ping)
    pingAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    pingAudioPlayer.play()
}catch {
    print("Error getting the audio file")
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I realized I have an older version of Xcode and think Swift has had some updates since. I changed it and am now telling the audio player what to play, but still no sound. See update

Comment: My only experience with audio is with MPMediaPlayer so I'm not really sure what the problem would be here.